# How to get Cookies in the websocket connection?

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:1255
Origin: http://testt:8080
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: json
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: sGGDklOmMNFmY2AniKkkGw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
```

this is what I've get during the handshake of websocket, but how could I get from here the cookie id?, I've thinked to pass the cookie after the handshake is done, but will that be correct?

where are the cookies hidden?

its connecting to my java socket, what class I can use in this case to get the cookie? or it would be better if I get it from the string above...

Answer (score 0):

The string above does not contain any cookie. The browser sends cookies using a "Cookie" HTTP header, which is not in that request.

If you want the browser to send the webpage cookie, you have to put the WebSocket server and the web server in the same domain, otherwise the cookie won't be send.

It is technically possible to return cookies in the negotiation HTTP response (in a "Set-Cookie" HTTP header), and it will be resend in the next connection.